# Infinite loop: while(Time.time < Time.time + 5f)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am going insane. For the life of me I cannot work out why the following code is causing Unity to freeze up as soon as I press play. It's an otherwise empty project with the script attached to an empty gameobject. In the console, nothing appears, not even the initial `Debug.Log("Step 1");`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Reels : MonoBehaviour
{    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Step 1");
        TestFunction(1f);
    }

    private void TestFunction(float duration)
    {
        float endTimer = Time.time + duration;
        Debug.Log("Step 2 " +  endTimer);

        while (Time.time < endTimer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Step 3");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Please save my sanity.

Comment: You won't see the log message until the next frame, which you are never getting to.

Comment: I don't see "Step 1" though despite it should be the very first line of code I wrote that is executed.

Comment: You would see it if your function ever exited, but it doesn't because it's an endless loop.  Time.time < endTimer  will always be true (unless duration is less than zero) because Time.time doesn't change inside the loop.  It only changes at the end of the frame, which you are preventing.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for Time.realtimeSinceStartup and the following quote stood out: "This is the time in seconds since the start of the application, and **is not constant if called multiple times in a frame**" I suppose that, by omission, Time.time does not update when called multiple times per frame. I think I get it now, thank you!

Comment: That's not "by omission" — the docs explicitly tell you it's only updated once per frame, defining it as: "The time at the *beginning* of this frame (Read Only)."

Comment: I guess what I meant to say is that if Time.time explicitly said "**is constant if called multiple times in a frame**" in the same way as the Time.realtimeSinceStartup documentation, it would have given me more of a clue as to what was going wrong. I'm not blaming the documentation, but rather my interpretation of it and my understanding of the engine in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Time.time` is a read only field that [stores the time at the beginning of the frame](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html), and the way you wrote that code, the frame never ends, because you'll never get out of that loop.

Comment: Use [Time.realtimeSinceStartup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) instead.

Comment: If I do the following code though, `theTime` increments as expected in the console.
        `theTime = Time.time;`
        `Debug.Log(theTime);`  I guess I'm having a hard time understanding exactly why it isn't updating as it appears to be elsewhere. The documentation didn't help.

Comment: That's not an endless loop.  Time.time is updated every frame, which is also how aften Update is getting called.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Blindy, Chuck, and Ted Bigham. I've definitely learnt something from this!

Comment: @Chuck that is somewhat misguided recommendation - busy wait for x seconds *is not* the way to implement delays in games (or any UI for that matter)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah I understand lol, it's going to lock the frame for however long OP chooses to delay, but wanted to narrow the scope of the response here to strictly what OP was asking about. Ultimately this is a Q&A site and not a tutorial site for coroutines, threads, etc.

Comment: @Chuck basically trolling OP. Fair.